# Center-alignment in tabular in LaTeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is part of my code in TexStudio, I'm trying to center-align some text inside left-aligned table, but it doesn't work.
The error is very strange, looks like

```
Something's wrong - perhaps a missing item
```

I've tried also to use `\centering` function, although there were no error, it doesn't change anything (the text inside remains left-aligned)...

How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,openany]{article}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,top=20mm,    bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,hyperindex,breaklinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{euscript} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l}

    \begin{center}
    \LARGE{Вариант 1.}
    \end{center}     \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful what to tell the users what your final goal is. You already have an idea of a solution, but there might be an even better one.

Comment: When you use an `l` column, the width of the column is set as wide as the widest content in that column. Since you only have one entry, the `l` column  is as wide as the text, so trying to center the text is not gonna give any different result. Quick fix; since you load the `tabularx` package, you can replace `\begin{tabular}{l}` with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}`. Also, you should not use the `center` environment here, but `\centering\arraybackslash` (if you only have one column).

Comment: Maybe you want to centre a single cell in an otherwise left-aligned column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For centering text just in one cell in column you need to use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`. For demo see MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=20mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
left aligned text                       \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Variante 1}   \\
    \hline
again left aligned text                 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE is derived from yours. In it I left only necessary packages which is needed for this demo. I also add vertical in horizontal lines that the aligning of text is observable. IN real application just omit them (if you not like to have)

[image]

And by the way, package `hyperref` should be last in preamble.